# PostgreSQL get current week and previous week revenue from Date column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to get `revenue of facilities` from my tables in `week format` but not to get `current week revenue` and `previous week revenue` and further more weeks.
I have joined my all tables and have all relevant columns to calculate revenue but not able to get revenue week wise for every facility.

`Question: Get facility wise revenue for past 3 weeks.`

To `calculate the revenue`, i used this formula: `revenue =  (SalePrice*SKUQuantity) – ((PurchasePrice*SKUQuantity)+(PurchasePrice*ReturnQuantity))`

This is the format I want my result in.

[image: This is format I want my result to be in]

`Relevant Tables:`

Sale Order Table:

[image]

Sale Order Details:

[image]

Comment: There is no `int(10)  in Postgres. Looks like you are actually using MySQL, not Postgres

Comment: well i want to use postgreSQL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your formula as-is, [conditional aggregation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36652078/how-to-do-conditional-aggregation-in-postgres) by week and grouping by `"FacilityId"`:

```sql
select 
  "FacilityId",
  sum(... your revenue formula here ...)
   filter (where date_trunc('week', "DeliveryDate") = date_trunc('week', now())) as "CURRENT_WEEK",
  sum(... your revenue formula here ...)
   filter (where date_trunc('week', "DeliveryDate") = date_trunc('week', now() - interval '1 week')) as "LAST_WEEK"
from sale_order so 
inner join order_details od on so.id = od."SaleOrderId"
group by so."FacilityId";
```

Please note that camel-case names need to be enclosed in double quotes.

Comment: can we use case when instead of filter where?

Comment: any specific reason for using double quotes for column?

Comment: Yes, you can use `case` (pls. follow the link in the answer), sum with filter is cleaner and more readable IMHO. Using double quotes for mixed-case names is part of PostgreSQL [syntax](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-syntax-lexical.html).